# event_start_date formatting month_09_3 instead of September

Tags: ee2, solspace, calendar, solspace-calendar

I am using {event_start_date format="%M %j"} to get the format eg Sep 19

But in some cases it is outputting the month as "month_09_3" if the URl segments match the date of that event.

My code is below:

```
        {exp:calendar:cal
                date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
                show_months="10"
                pad_short_weeks="n"
                {if segment_2 !="all"}calendar_name="{segment_2}"{/if}
        }
        {events}  
            <tr>
                <td><strong>{event_start_date format="%M %j"} {if event_multi_day}- {event_end_date format="%M %j"}{/if}</strong></td> 
                <td>{event_title}</td>
                <td>{event_calendar_title}</td>
            </tr>
        {/events}
            {if no_results}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    There are currently no events to display.
                </td>
            </tr>{/if}


        {/exp:calendar:cal}
```

The url example would be http://www.domain.com/new-calendar/culture/2013/09/19/ segment 2 being the calendar_name.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Calendar are you using?
What version of EE are you using?

Comment: Hi, EE v2.5.2 and Calendar 1.8.5, I was using 1.8.4 but updated to see if it would fix it.

Comment: Is it me, or do you have a missing `{/if}` for `{if no_results}`?

Comment: Soz that's just a mistake in this snippet. Not on the website.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my side. Have you tested the above code on a completely, absolutely blank EE template with nothing whatsoever on it besides the code? You might need to contact us directly at http://support.solspace.com/ with CP/FTP credentials so we can have a look. Thanks!

Comment: I was using mini cal and another cal tag on the same page, I embedded these in their own templates and it seems to be working now. So maybe we cannot use multiple solspace calendar tags on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you should be able to use multiple calendars on one page but in this case it didn't work so embedded each calendar in templates to solve.